# the speed is too slow for vtkWindowToImageFilter, how to speed it?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, vtk

Currently, we need to use vtk in my project. We want to obtain the off sreen rendering picture and show it. We use vtkWindowToImageFilter to obtain the rendering picture. However, we find it's too slow. My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import vtk, qimage2ndarray

class vtkLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(vtkLabel, self).__init__()
        cone = vtk.vtkConeSource()
        mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        mapper.SetInputConnection(cone.GetOutputPort())
        actor = vtk.vtkActor()
        actor.SetMapper(mapper)

        ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        ren.AddActor(actor)
        renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
        renWin.AddRenderer(ren)
        renWin.SetOffScreenRendering(1)
        imageFilter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
        imageFilter.SetInput(renWin)

        self.ren = ren
        self.renWin = renWin
        self.imageFilter = imageFilter

    def resizeEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        super(vtkLabel, self).resizeEvent(QMouseEvent)
        print(self.width(), self.height())
        self.renWin.SetSize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.renWin.Render()
        self.imageFilter.Modified()
        self.imageFilter.Update()
        displayImg = self.imageFilter.GetOutput()

        dims = displayImg.GetDimensions()
        from vtk.util.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy
        numImg = vtk_to_numpy(displayImg.GetPointData().GetScalars())
        numImg = numImg.reshape(dims[1], dims[0], 3)
        numImg = numImg.transpose(0, 1, 2)
        numImg = np.flipud(numImg)

        displayQImg = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(numImg)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(displayQImg)
        self.pixmap = pixmap

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        super(vtkLabel, self).paintEvent(QPaintEvent)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        width = self.width()
        height = self.height()
        painter.drawPixmap(QPoint(0, 0), self.pixmap, QRect(0, 0, width, height))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(500,500)
        self.imageLabel = vtkLabel()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.imageLabel)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

In this code, we find the speed is slow when we change the window size. And the weird thing is that the speed would be fast if I delete/comment the code "renWin.SetOffScreenRendering(1)".

How can I speed up this code? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just trying to embed VTK into a QMainWindow? There's a proper VTK class for that. I'll post an example if that's what you're after...

Comment: Thank you very mush for reply. Yes, I want to embed VTK into QT. However, I don't want to a QVTK class, for example QVTKRenderWindowInteractor, because QT is more convenient to add more complicate operation than VTK.

Comment: What kind of _more complicated operations_ are you thinking? Do you mean functionality within the render such as clicking on points and dragging bits around? Or do you mean outside of the render such as adding buttons and sliders which may alter the image? The QVTKRenderWindowInteractor is fairly easy. You can box it into a QWidget then it's normal QT after that...

Comment: Yes, drag the point or something else. Thus, I want to implement the GUI operation by QT, and the VTK is used only for render.

Comment: I really think you're trying to reinvent the wheel in that case. You can change the way VTK mouse interaction works by giving it a different interaction style - the default is pretty horrible. Try adding `iren.setStylevtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera())` before `iren.Start()` to a generic VTK example and see if that works better for you.

Comment: Mouse interaction is arguably easier in VTK and Qt. Just use `iren.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", callback)`. There's a list somewhere of what the events can be.

Comment: However, in my project, all the GUI operation is implemented by QT. Thus, I want to use QT to deal with the operation for 3D rendering. It's the reason why I want to copy the picture from VTK render window, and show it in QT. Of course, if I can not solve this problem, I have no choise but use QVTKRenderWindowInteractor.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do - I just don't think it's practical. In answer to your original question, I don't see any way to speed your code up. I would say resize your renWin to match your window size but you're already doing that. It runs fast enough on my computer. Does ``renWin.SetDPI(...)`` help at all?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea for renWin.SetDPI. A very weird thing is that renWin.SetOffScreenRendering(1) and renWin.SetOffScreenRendering(0) would make very large difference. Have you tried it? Do you know the reason?

Comment: When I set off screen rendering off the Qt window doesn't resize the contents on window resize, and I get a vtk window that work fine. SetOffScreenRendering allows you to take renders without going through a vtkRenderWindow. You quite definately  need it on.